# Facebook Graph API - Wrong Image Orientation

Tags: ios, facebook, graph, orientation

I fix my app's orientation to be landscape only.

This is how I get the screenshot.

```
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

and I change the orientation through

```
UIImage * landscapeImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: img.CGImage scale: 1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationRight];
```

I use fb iOS SDK to post the screenshot to facebook.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               landscapeImage, @"picture",
                               SOME_URL,@"link",
                               @"Have fun",@"name",
                               @"Join the fun",@"message",
                               @"0",@"position",
                               nil];
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                andParams:params
                            andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                              andDelegate:self];
```

The problem is that I cannot control the orientation and the orientation of the uploaded images are always either

```
-----
|   |
| P |
-----
```

or

```
-----
|   |
| q |
-----
```

but i want the image to laid horizontally(landscape).

```
-------
|      |  
-------
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1024, 768));
        [rotateImg drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
        UIImage *landscapeImage = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain];
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

here is how to resolve the problem.

UIimages's orientation is for "DISPLAY" only, you need to redraw the image